# How to add non-visible Node in VirtualStringTree?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Currently I have this code to add some nodes to a `VST`

```
function AddVSTStructure(AVST: TCustomVirtualStringTree; ANode: PVirtualNode; AObject: TDATArecord): PVirtualNode;
var
  Data: PUserData;
begin
  Result := AVST.AddChild(ANode);
  Data := AVST.GetNodeData(Result);
  AVST.ValidateNode(Result, false);
  Data^.FObject := AObject;
end;

//adding node
VDT1.BeginUpdate;
try
  DATArecord.name := 'nodename';
  DATArecord.Visible:= False;
  AddVSTStructure(VDT1, nil, DATArecord);
finally
  VDT1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

I want to add node in non-visible state, I mean completely invisible.

I know I can set the visibility of the node after adding it using `VDT1.IsVisible[Node] := boolean;` But i want to set it non-visible before showing in the tree considering the record I add is set to `DATArecord.Visible:= False;`

So, if `Datarecord.visible` is equal to true, add the node with visible state. If its false, add the node with non-visible state how can i do that?

Comment: What is stopping you from setting `AVST.IsVisible[Result] := AObject.Visible;` immediately after creating the node? The user is not going to see the node added since you are inside the `(Begin/End)Update` pair at the time you create the node.

Comment: @RemyLebeau wow that easy  i really start to believe that i am really stupid or even mental retarded . Thank you very much that was very simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply set the node's `IsVisible` property immediately after you create the node:

```
Result := AVST.AddChild(ANode);
AVST.IsVisible[Result] := AObject.Visible; // <-- add this
```

The user is not going to see the node added since `AddVSTStructure()` is being called inside the `(Begin/End)Update` pair, so the add does not perform any onscreen update.